# Why cant we call base class constructor without creating object of derived class in multiple inheritance (java)

Tags: java

```
class A
{
  public A()
  {...}
}

class B extends A
{
  public B(String s)
  {...}
}

class C extends B
{
  public C()
  {...}
}

class const
{
  public static void main(String a[])
  {
      B object=new B("Hello"); // gives error.
  }
}
```

Why is the compiler giving an error ->
error.java:18: error: constructor B in class B cannot be applied to given types;
class C extends B
^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Comment: is code snippte too short?/

Comment: because your constructor in C calls implicit the constructor B() which doesnt exist. you have to call the super constructor (B) with a string parameter.

Comment: What's inside the constructors?

Comment: B class constructor would implicitly call class A constructor.How will arguments matter.?

Comment: If there's an error it should be something like **No enclosing instance of const found**.

Comment: The error shouldn't be at the line where you're creating an instance of B. It should be in the C constructor. Check your compile-time errors carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the constructor of child

Constructor creates an object of its type, so if you call parent constructor you are able to create only parent instace. Thats why it is not allowed and you have to rewrite C class as follows:

```
class C extends B
{
    public C(String s)
    {
        super(s);
        ...
    }
}
```

NOTE: error is in this case:

```
C object=new C("Hello"); // gives error.
```

Comment: This solved the problem.But question is what if I wanted to call constructor of B class without C's Object ? Is that possible.

Comment: in your case there is no error, your posted code should work error is probably in C class because of avoiding `super(String)`, look at @JonSkeet comment @Chaitanya

Comment: Rt. errors in C class constructor. Thnx